# Angular Reactive Forms: is it possible to create custom form control component with 'must have' validation included?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I've created my custom form control for `tree` of selects, I tested it already and the value is set properly. There is one problem, I want to set this control as `VALID` only if all selects are selected. So I also implemented `Validators` but there has to be something wrong because the control is set as `valid` every time. It's triggering my `validate()` method and returning expected values. Could someone look at my code and give me some tips how to achive that?

Code

```
  selector: 'app-cascading-picklist',
  templateUrl: './cascading-picklist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cascading-picklist.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CascadingPicklistComponent),
    multi: true
  }, {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CascadingPicklistComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class CascadingPicklistComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validators, OnInit {
  @Input() parentList: FormList;
  expanded = false;
  flatLists: FormList[];
  selectedValues: string[] = [];
  hierarchicalForm = new FormGroup({});
  public value = '';
  onChange: (value) => void = () => {
  };
  onTouched: () => void = () => {
  };
  onValidationChange: any = () => {
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.flatLists = this.getFlatPickLists();
    this.generateForm();
    this.selectedValues.push(this.flatLists[0].ID);
  }

  getFlatPickLists() {
    let flatList: FormList[] = [];
    flatList = [...this.getAllLists(this.parentList)];
    return flatList;
  }

  getAllLists(formList: FormList) {
    let lists: FormList[] = [formList];
    if (formList.ChildPickLists) {
      for (const list of formList.ChildPickLists) {
        if (list) {
          lists = [...lists, ...this.getAllLists(list)];
        }
      }
    }
    return lists;
  }

  generateForm() {
    this.flatLists.forEach(list => {
      this.hierarchicalForm.addControl(list.ID, new FormControl());
    });
  }

  onValueChange() {
    const rawValue = Object.values(this.hierarchicalForm.getRawValue()) as PickListItem[];
    const nullIndex = rawValue.findIndex(element => !!!element);
    this.selectedValues = [this.flatLists[0].ID, ...rawValue.splice(0, nullIndex).map(el => el.Value)];
    this.resetHiddenControls();
    this.writeValue(this.getHierarchicalPath());
  }

  resetHiddenControls() {
    Object.keys(this.hierarchicalForm.controls).forEach(control => {
      if (!this.selectedValues.includes(control)) {
        if (this.hierarchicalForm.controls[control].value) {
          this.hierarchicalForm.controls[control].setValue(null, {emitEvent: false});
        }
      }
    });
  }

  getHierarchicalPath() {
    let path = '';
    this.selectedValues.forEach(value => {
      const selectedValue = this.hierarchicalForm.controls[value] ? this.hierarchicalForm.controls[value].value : null;
      if (selectedValue) {
        path = `${path}${selectedValue.Label}/`;
      }
    });
    return path.slice(0, -1);
  }

  public registerOnChange(fn: (value) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  public writeValue(newValue): void {
    this.value = newValue;
    this.onChange(newValue);
    this.onValidationChange();
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onValidationChange = fn;
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    this.selectedValues.forEach(controlName => {
      if (this.hierarchicalForm.controls[controlName] && !this.hierarchicalForm.controls[controlName].value) {
        return {cascadingPicklist: true};
      }
    });
    return null;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
       (click)="expanded = !expanded" readonly>
<ng-container *ngIf="expanded">
  <form [formGroup]="hierarchicalForm">
    <ng-select *ngFor="let list of flatLists"
               [items]="list.PickListItems"
               [placeholder]="list.Placeholder"
               bindLabel="Label"
               appendTo="body"
               dropdownPosition="bottom"
               [class.d-none]="!(list.ID | isSelectVisible : selectedValues)"
               (ngModelChange)="onValueChange()"
               [formControlName]="list.ID">
    </ng-select>
  </form>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz/codepen example implementation to catch better the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validate() error is on using `return` inside a `forEach` function.
Create a local variable and assign to it the value only if you have an empty select:

```
  validate(control?: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    let result = null;
    this.selectedValues.forEach(controlName => {
      if (
        this.hierarchicalForm[controlName] &&
        !this.hierarchicalForm[controlName].value
      ) {
        result = { cascadingPicklist: true };
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validators-with-select?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

A smarter solution could be to use the `every` function:

```
return this.selectedValues.every(controlName => 
      !!(this.hierarchicalForm[controlName] &&
        this.hierarchicalForm[controlName].value
      )) ? null : { cascadingPicklist: true };
```

Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validators-with-select-w2rvwb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts